# Python replace front substring and back substring

Tags: python, string, optimization, replace

Let's say I have a string `"abc_123_def"` and I want to "remove" `"abc_"` and `"_def"` and be left with `"123"`.

I currently have two replace statements:

```
s = "abc_123_def"
s.replace("abc_",'')
s.replace("_def",'')
```

Is there a better, one-liner way to do so?

Comment: I want to remove those specific sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "abc_123_def"
s = s.replace("abc_",'').replace("_def",'')
```

Comment: I didn't realize python let you chain methods like that!

Comment: Any decent language will let you chain calls like that so long as the call returns a value.

Comment: Yes because `s.replace("abc_",'')` returns a string, which can then be put into another function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like below, to exactly identify the values between underscores.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'abc_123_def'
>>> re.findall('_(.*?)_', s)[0]
'123'
>>>
```